# Could not open input file: artisan - Laravel existing web app - PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-artisan

I have an existing Web application in Laravel and I'm trying to add a GDPR functionality for cookies with PhpStorm.

I'm getting this error while trying to run the application.

> Could not open input file: artisan

I'm using:

- PhpStorm
- XAMP server locally

What I have discovered, the developer have built the structure in a different way that I know, I mean, the Laravel packages and resources reside in project folder since the the whole application is structured in Online store folder like " Online_store/project"

See the attached pictures:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I'm a beginner into Laravel, can you tell me more what exactly I need to do and where? This is the configuration file for my setup to run the app

[image]

Comment: 1) You are using custom type of Run/Debug Configuration that is provided by some Laravel related plugin; it's definitely does not come from PhpStorm built-in functionality. 2) Since the actual `artisan` command is located inside a subfolder .. you need to specify the working folder so your OS/PHP is able to locate that file (or perhaps use `project/artisan` instead of just `artisan`). Project root is the default working folder.

Comment: `cd project` to get to the artisan file and then `php artisan`

Comment: Friom the treminal I have run php project/artisan and worked just fine but when I hit the run process I'm getting the same error

Comment: @SorinBuzatu That Run/Debug Configuration that you are using is provided by custom Laravel related plugin, not PhpStorm itself. You better ask plugin author on how to properly use it for such situation. I would just type the command manually in built-in terminal .. or perhaps try "PHP Script" type of configuration where you can pass any params to a PHP CLI script (which is what `artisan` is)